# sympy.sympify() does not perform substitutions

Tags: python, sympy

this works as expected:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> (x, y, z) = symbols("x y z")
>>> y = x
>>> z = y
>>> z
x
```

however `sympify()` does not perform the substitution:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> y = sympify('x')
>>> z = sympify('y')
>>> z
y
```

`z` should be set to `x`.

are there any flags i can pass to `sympify()` to get it to substitute? i'm using sympy version 0.7.1.rc1 and python 2.7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the difference between `sympy` symbols and Python names.

```
>>> y = sympify('x')
```

Here you've created a symbol `x` referred to by a name `y`.

```
>>> z = sympify('y')
```

Now you create a symbol `y` referred to by a name `z`. Note that the symbol `y` and the local name `y` have NOTHING to do with each other. Sympy does not care that you have a variable named y when you say `sympify('y')` -- it's not inspecting your local namespace.

What you probably want is:

```
>>> z = sympify(y)
```

i.e. assigning `z` to the *symbol pointed to by* `y`; this gets you what you expect:

```
>>> z
x
```

Also note that the `sympify` call is entirely redundant in this case, you really should just be doing:

```
>>> z = y
```